# Custom Integer Formatting in Swift for an Astrology App

Tags: swift, variables, types

I’ve long struggled how to come up with an elegant solution to this problem. It’s an astrology app project and what I’m trying to implement is a positioning system.

```swift
struct Position {
    var sign: Int 
    var degrees: Int
    var minutes: Int
}
```

In this system the sign can only be 1…12. So for instance if 13 is passed into the sign variable, it should start over from 1.
Degrees should implement the same logic and be limited from 0…29. So 30 passed into degrees variable should convert to 1.
Minutes are limited from 0…59. Same logic.

I’m struggling to implement it and for it to look logical and minimalistic. Do I need to create a custom type for storing such value? The actual format the app should use is, for example: 1 23’ 45".

If I was to add 1 minute to 12 sign 29 degrees 59 minutes, it should convert to 0 0 0. Much like Date works.

Comment: If `13` is passed to a 1...12 variable, do you need to keep the original value of `13`?

Comment: "Do I need to create a custom type for storing such value?" You already did.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest to keep sign as `0..11`.

Comment: @Sulthan, no, the original value shouldn’t be kept. It should work in the same manner the Date format works. If you were adding 1 minute to 59 minutes, it would convert to 1 hour 0 minutes. That’s what I am trying to achieve. If I was to add 1 minute to 12 sign 29 degrees 59 minutes, it should convert to 0 0 0.

Comment: You could use computed properties, see here in the Swift docs: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: @Sulthan, that’s a good point to keep the sign 0…11. I see.

Comment: @koen, thank you, reading it now. I’m still new to swift.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that the representation of sign, degrees and minutes is technically just a human representation of a single number. Your example with `Date` is a good one because that should make your realize that `Date` is internally represented by a single `Double` and we only convert it to components when needed (and the conversion is very complicated with dates).

Therefore, the first thing I propose is to represent all three values by a single number (which is actually the total number of *minutes*).

Then every calculation can be just a modification of this number.

The concept I will use is pretty common and it is actually the same as with positional digits (e.g. number `1234` = `((((1 * 10) + 2) * 10) + 3) * 10 + 4`). You might also know this concept from calculating hours & minutes from the number of seconds.

```
struct Position: CustomStringConvertible {
    // considering sign to be 0...11
    static let signCount = 12
    // degrees are 0...29
    static let degreeCount = 30
    // minute are 0...29
    static let minuteCount = 60
    // the total number of possible values, value is 0...(maxValue - 1)
    static let maxValue = signCount * degreeCount * minuteCount

    // if value is outside the permitted range, normalize it
    private static func normalizeValue(_ value: Int) -> Int {
        if value >= maxValue {
            // simple modulo operation
            return value % maxValue
        }

        if value < 0 {
            // make negative values positive and within the correct range
            return maxValue + value % maxValue
        }

        return value
    }

    private var value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = Self.normalizeValue(value)
    }

    init(sign: Int, degrees: Int, minutes: Int) {
        // calculate position value from components
        let value = ((sign * Self.degreeCount) + degrees) * Self.minuteCount + minutes
        self.value = Self.normalizeValue(value)
    }

    var sign: Int {
        return value / (Self.degreeCount * Self.minuteCount)
    }
    var degrees: Int {
        return (value / Self.minuteCount) % Self.degreeCount
    }
    var minutes: Int {
        return value % Self.minuteCount
    }

    func adding(_ position: Position) -> Position {
        return Position(value: value + position.value)
    }

    func adding(sign: Int, degrees: Int, minutes: Int) -> Position {
        let position = Position(sign: sign, degrees: degrees, minutes: minutes)
        return adding(position)
    }

    var description: String {
        return "Sign \(sign + 1), \(degrees)° \(minutes)′"
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let position = Position(sign: 23, degrees: 29, minutes: 59)
print(position) // Sign 12, 29° 59′
print(position.adding(sign: 0, degrees: 0, minutes: 2)) // Sign 1, 0° 1′
print(position.adding(sign: -13, degrees: 0, minutes: 0)) // Sign 11, 29° 59′
```

Note that I am adding `+1` to the sign only when formatting. However, if you want to store sign as `1..12` the code can be trivially updated to add/subtract `1` when loading/storing `sign` into the position value.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I never considered doing it like this. My solution is much more, ehh basic? Definitely going to be trying this in some of my projects.

Comment: Just noticed something else about yours, perhaps you could answer a burning question for me. So you're doing an `init()` and referencing a static function. How do static functions effect performance? Generally speaking that is. In mine I INIT and store the value as or I could do it in the set as well, but I don't use a static method to accomplish it. Is there any real difference between the two that I should consider?

Comment: @xTwisteDx Static function would be generally slightly better in performance than a virtual function. On a struct all methods are technically linked statically (there is no inheritance). The performance difference would be negligible anyway. You should care more about readability than performance unless you are working on something when these things really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple computed property that will get the job done for you. In my example I've done it on a `0 based index` in other words `upper limit - 1`. If you wish to remove that functionality, change every `0 to a 1` and increment every `max:` by `+1`

```
class Position {
    var sign: Int {
        get{ return getConstrainedValue(value: self.sign, max: 12) }
        set{}
    }

    var degrees: Int {
        get{ return getConstrainedValue(value: self.degrees, max: 29) }
        set{}
    }

    var minutes: Int {
        get{ return getConstrainedValue(value: self.minutes, max: 59) }
        set{}
    }

    func getConstrainedValue(value: Int, max limit: Int) -> Int {
        // If value is greater than limit, return first value, 0.
        // Otherwise, if value is less than 0, return the limit.
        // Otherwise return the value.
        return value > limit ? 1 : value < 1 ? limit : value
    }

    init(sign: Int, degrees: Int, minutes: Int) {
        self.sign = sign
        self.degrees = degrees
        self.minutes = minutes
    }
}

let test = Position(sign: 12, degrees: -1, minutes: 58)
print("sign: \(test.sign) degrees: \(test.degrees) minutes: \(test.minutes)")
```

Comment: This is a good solution for different use cases but the OP specifically asks to add `1 minute` to `(12, 29, 59)` to make it `(0, 0, 0)` :)

Comment: Note the min value for `sign` is `1` :)

Comment: Yeh, I originally had it on a 0 based index, but came back and changed it to a count-based and forgot that. I'm getting the feeling the OP got his answer and bounced haha. Sad #noRepDay.